# How to implement multi-currency staking?

Tags: staking, balances, assets, pallet-staking, security

I was wondering what would be the best way to achieve multi-currency staking given:

- It's on a solo chain
- Foreign assets are bridged (like Eth or BTC, pallet-asset can be used)
- No conversion from foreign currency to native currency should happen

Apart from this, anything can be done.

I guess the most hardcore answer would be to fork and change the staking pallet but wanted some opinions.

Comment: To my knowledge, you must tweak the staking pallet.